# Efficient way of waiting for a variable to be set?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am looking for an efficient way of checking if a variable has been set in my Angular application, so I don't have to keep checking if it has been set. I have a service that loads all products into a variable, when the user first requests the page. Example:

```
export class ProductService {
    public products: Product[];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    init(): any {
        if (!this.products) {
            this.http.get<Product[]>("https://my-api.com/GetAllProducts").subscribe(products => {
                this.products = products;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I then call this simply saying `productService.init()` in my `app.component.ts` file, which makes sure it initializes the products  for later use. However, I also have a method that grabs a product from a product ID:

```
getProductFromProductId(productId: string) {
    return this.products.find(x => x.id === productId);
}
```

This `getProductFromProductId` method gets called on every page at least once. Let's imagine the `init()` method takes 2000ms to load, because there are a lot of products, calling `getProductFromProductId()` would fail because `products` is not set yet. To fix this, I could do something like:

```
getProductFromProductId(productId: string) {
    if(!this.products) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Products not loaded yet");
            getProductFromProductId(productId);
        }, 10);
    } else {
        return this.products.find(x => x.id === productId);
    }
}
```

The above code checks if `products` has been set every 10ms. If not, it simply calls the method again.

However, let's imagine I have 10 methods in this service. That's a lot of "**not loaded yet**" possibilities, which means I would have to repeat the same code 10 times (or move it to a function, but you get the point). The biggest issue is that `getProductFromProductId` and `init` are both called at the same time, so we need to wait for `init` to finish, basically.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your product list to an Observable. I'd recommend a BehaviorSubject.

```
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';

export class ProductService {
    public products: BehaviorSubject<Product[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    init(): any {
        if (!this.products) {
            this.http.get<Product[]>("https://my-api.com/GetAllProducts").subscribe(products => {

                if(products){
                    this.products.next(products);
                }

            });
        }
    }

    getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
        return this.products.asObservable();
    }

}
```

Then let your ts-files subscribe to the BehaviorSubject. As soon as it gets filled all subscribers get informed an can react.

**TS-files**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe( list => {

        if(list) {
            // fill your local list
            this.productList = list;

            // or call a method that processes this list
            this.processProductList(list);

            // or other actions
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Returning all the products from the service isn't really a good way of doing this, in my opinion. If I have 20 components that require me to grab a product from a product id, I need to repeat the same logic 20 times, instead of calling a method on the service. See my own answer I made from my own research

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't able to use [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) (no idea why, but I simply couldn't get it to work), I opted with a regular [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject) instead. Here's an example:

**product.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    public products = new Array<Product>();
    public productsSubject: Subject<Product[]> = new Subject();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    init(): any {
        this.http.get<Product[]>("https://my-api.com/GetAllProducts").subscribe(products => {
            this.products = products;
            this.productsSubject.next(products);
        });
    }

    getProductByProductId(productId: string): Observable<Product> {
        if (this.products.length > 0)
            return of(this.products.find(x => x.id === productId));

        return new Observable(observer => {
            this.productsSubject
                .subscribe(products => {
                    var p = products.find(x => x.id === productId);
                    observer.next(p);
                    observer.complete();
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Remember to add `import { of } from 'rxjs';` at the top, if you want to use `of()`.

And then in our components, we can simply do:

**random.component.ts**

```
this.productsService.getProductByProductId(productId)
    .subscribe(product => {
        //do something with product
    });
```

This makes sure our service methods are relatively small and easy to understand, while the code for the components are small and understandable as well.